# Extra character while reading from MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, cobol

I want to read records from MQ in a COBOL program. In the queue the records seems to be correct but the problem is that the message I get using MQGET in program has extra characters and the message is corrupt. How can I solve this problem?

For example the Message in queue is as below:

```
123456
```

The message from COBOL program is:

```
1.2.3.4.5.6
```

Comment: What are the hexadecimal values of the extra characters?

Comment: We have no idea what you do. Please add code how you get the data in COBOL including the relevant definitions.

Comment: The hexadecimal value is ´F0´

Comment: Have you tried adding `MQGMO-CONVERT`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the message written to the queue is in some other format (e.g. cp1250 , utf-8 etc.) and your code is converting it to another. You will need to find out in your code.

Comment: How can I find out the  format of message that I get from QUEUE?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not willing to let us look into your code then you can watch the message with [RFHUtil](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil)
and then show us some screenshots of the data and MD section.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your character conversion wrong.  Make sure you correctly set the CCSID before you do your MQGET.  Also, maybe check the queue manager and channel defaults, and make sure they are what you expect.